# Not show Correct Scores java

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner

in my code , i have 2 array name and score and length of both is 2

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    private static Scanner key = new Scanner (System.in); 

    public static void main (String [] args){

        String [] name = new String [2];
        int [] score = new int [2];

        readInfo(name, score);
        showInfo(name, score);


    }

    public static void readInfo (String [] name, int [] score){


        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){

            System.out.print("Name no."+(i + 1)+": ");
            name [i] = key.next();

            for (int j = 0; j < score.length; j++){

                System.out.print("Score no."+(j + 1)+": ");
                score [j] = key.nextInt();


            }

            System.out.println("");

        }


    }


    public static void showInfo (String [] name, int [] score){

        System.out.println("Name\tScores\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){

            System.out.print(name [i]);

            for (int j = 0; j < score.length; j++ )
                System.out.println("\t"+score [j]+"\t");


            System.out.println("");
        }

    }







}
```

when i input names and scores, in output only show second scores for both names.

```
Name no.1: john
Score no.1: 17
Score no.2: 19

Name no.2: jack
Score no.1: 12
Score no.2: 18

Name    Scores

john    12  
        18  

jack    12  
        18
```

this is my problem how can i fix it?

Comment: `int [] score = new int [2];` creates space for 2 `int`s, but you have 4 scores.

Answer (score 1):

For the second iteration - pertaining to the second name - you are overwriting the first set of scores that were inputted. You need to make the score array a 2d array of dimension 2x2.

```
int[][] score = new int[2][2];
```

Then, in the nested for loops, reference score like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
     ...
     for(int j = 0; j < score[0].length; j++) {
          score[i][j] // score referenced like this
     }
     ...
}
```

This way we have two separate arrays of length two for each name.

Comment: what if score array length is 3?

Comment: If you need a variable length container to hold your scores, consider an ArrayList, to which you can append any number of scores

Comment: If you know for sure that the score array needs to be of length three then you can change the dimensions of the array. int[][] score = new int[i][j] where i is the number of names and j is the number of scores. If the number of scores is variable you need to look at an ArrayList like Matt Solarz mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You have four total scores, and an array that only holds two. When you run readInfo, the second name's scores overwrite the data in the scores array that were stored there from the first name. You would need to have enough spaces in the array for all the scores, or choose a different way to store this data.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it like this:

```
public class Test{

private static Scanner key = new Scanner (System.in); 

public static void main (String [] args){

    String [] name = new String [2];
    int [] score = new int [name.length*2];

    readInfo(name, score);
    showInfo(name, score);


}

public static void readInfo (String [] name, int [] score){


    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){

        System.out.print("Name no."+(i + 1)+": ");
        name [i] = key.next();

        for (int j = i*2; j < name.length+i*2; j++){

            System.out.print("Score no."+(j + 1)+": ");
            score [j] = key.nextInt();


        }

        System.out.println("");

    }


}


public static void showInfo (String [] name, int [] score){

    System.out.println("Name\tScores\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){

        System.out.print(name [i]);

        for (int j = i*2; j < name.length +i*2; j++ )
            System.out.println("\t"+score [j]+"\t");


        System.out.println("");
    }

}
}
```

what's happening here is that you have an array of names length 2, and you want 2 scores for each. That means your scores array needs to have a length of names*2:

```
int [] score = new int [name.length*2];
```

Then, when inputting the scores, score index 0 and 1 needs to be for person 1, and index 2 and 3 needs to be for person 2, hence:

```
for (int j = i*2; j < name.length+i*2; j++){

        System.out.print("Score no."+(j + 1)+": ");
        score [j] = key.nextInt();


    }
```

Then, the same thing needs to be done for read